# Sharing a mounted drive with samba on CentOS7

Tags: centos, samba, selinux

CentOS 7, samba issue: 0 Files/Folders when trying to share USB drive with EXT4 file system.

Samba Configuration file:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = 271-filesharing
security = user
map to guest = bad user
dns proxy = no

#============================ Share Definitions ============================== 
[Administrator]
path = /mnt/ELEMENTERY-1TB/
browsable =yes
writable = yes
public = no
valid users = RVS
```

I have user called RVS on samba. I can access samba share using my macbook pro when I use path to user's home directory.

I've done `sudo chown RVS:RVS -R /mnt/ELEMENTERY-1TB`. Here are the permissions of the drive:

```
[RVS@271 mnt]$ ls -al
total 4
drwxr-xr-x.  3 RVS  RVS    28 Sep 12 00:26 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 17 root root  224 Sep  9 11:27 ..
drwxrwxrwx.  4 RVS  RVS  4096 Sep 12 00:26 ELEMENTERY-1TB
```

I also mounted this drive as RVS user with `sudo mount /deb/sdb /mnt/ELEMENTERY-1TB`.

Is there something I have skipped in configuration/permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS  enables SELinux by default, which adds additional security restrictions on the system. Default policy mostly covers the typical/default configurations for confined software. When access is denied, usually a log entry is generated in audit logs in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

With a removable media you should consider mounting the device with SELinux [*context option*](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-Mounting_File_Systems.html#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Mounting_File_Systems-Context_Mounts). This way you avoid modifying your system's SELinux policy and the need for filesystem relabeling on the removable device. You can use `samba_share_t` if you only intend to make the mount point to be used with samba. If you use/label `user_home_t` type, the files will be treated as if they were in user home directory.

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb /mnt/ELEMENTERY-1TB \
      -o context="system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0"
```

Or in `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID=<...> /mnt/ELEMENTERY-1TB/ ext4 defaults,errors=remount-ro,context="system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0" 0 1
```

If you still have issues with SELinux, 
you can use [`audit2why`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/audit2why) to find out why access was denied, and possibly if a SELinux [boolean](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux_FAQ#What_are_SELinux_booleans_.3F) exists to allow access. In case you need to alter SELinux policy, you can use [`audit2allow`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/audit2allow) to generate a policy module to allow access.

There are also two booleans `samba_export_all_ro` and `samba_export_all_rw` when enabled allow samba to access (and share) any files. In this case this allows samba significantly more access than required and therefore *should not* be used in *this situation* as mount options can be configured easily.