# CentoOS 7 Samba Share USB NTFS

Tags: centos, usb, samba, selinux, ntfs

Cannot seem to find an answer which includes all of the specifics of my situation. I followed instructions in [Sharing a mounted drive with samba on CentOS7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391673/sharing-a-mounted-drive-with-samba-on-centos7), but still have a problem. I have CentOS 7 and a NTFS USB drive connected to it. I would like to share using Samba that drive with my other windows machines (Windows 10). I have successfully mounted the drive to /mymnt/win folder, and I can read the drive from the Linux host machine AND see the share from Windows 10 machine. However, when I attempt to browse into the share from windows I get a "You do not have permission to access \mediapc\LewisData7TB." I can access anonymously a pure Linux share from windows as well.

Here's the relevant /etc/fstab file entry:

/dev/sda2       /mymnt/win   ntfs-3g  rw,umask=0000,defaults 0 0 -o context="system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0"

Here's my /etc/samba/smb.conf file (homes/printers/print$ are all commented out):

```
[global]
workgroup = LEWISFAM
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = mediapc
dns proxy = no
security = user
map to guest = Bad User
passdb backend = tdbsam

printing = cups
printcap name = cups
load printers = yes
cups options = raw

[Anonymous]
path = /shares/anonymous
guest ok = yes
browsable = yes
writeable = yes

[LewisData7TB]
path = /mymnt/win
browsable =yes
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
```

When I attempt to configure for SELinux I do this command:

chcon -t samba_share_t /mymnt/win/

I get this error:

chcon: failed to change context of /mymnt/win/ to system_w:object_r:samba_share_t:s0: Operation not supported.

So, my goal is to access to read/write this drive from windows, but not quite there yet.

Comment: If there are no SELinux errors in audit log, it likely is a regular permission issue.

Comment: [Fedora Project Q&A](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/62838/selinux-ntfs-samba-share-problemworkaround/): NTFS does not support SELinux attributes. Try mount -o remount,context=system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0 /dev/sdxY

Comment: This is not a fix, but more information. I temporarily suspended SELinux using https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-redhat-how-to-set-selinux-modes/. setenforce permissive. This allows me now to browse into the drive from my windows machine and create files/folders (read/write). So, it is related to SELinux.

Comment: Kenneth, my original post shows the fstab entry with the -o parameter as you recommend... So, I don't think the remount command (not supported anyway on my Centos 7) will have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to post some more error messages as some form of progress, but I had the notion to try some commands again and found one of these final ones ended my journey successfully, and as I don't see an answer already posted, I'll take what I used from Kenneth that helped me and add it here myself:

This was causing issues for me on Fedora Linux 35 Workstation with my exFAT USB external hard disk drive that I had already been using fine in Files/Nautilus that would be only to my user account.

To be sure I wasn't just unfamiliar with Samba, I used commands such as `man smb.conf` to edit the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file with more knowledge, and `testparm` to validate the configuration.

```
sudo mount /dev/sd?? '/mnt/...' -o 'nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,x-gvfs-show,context="system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0"'
```

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/62838/selinux-ntfs-samba-share-problemworkaround/

That is the command that completed my solution.

It utilizes the same method of masking filesystem attributes like I had found in tutorial pages with my Fedora Linux distribution here: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/samba/
https://www.tecmint.com/setup-samba-file-sharing-for-linux-windows-clients/

```
sudo semanage fcontext --add --type "samba_share_t" /mnt/...
sudo restorecon -R /mnt/...
```

I was able to test that was necessary earlier using these broader commands:

```
> sudo setenforce Permissive
> sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Memory protection checking:     actual (secure)
Max kernel policy version:      33
```

https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-redhat-how-to-set-selinux-modes/
I had also noticed the bare directory when unmounted was a `mnt_t`, and when mounted and dysfunctional with Samba was `dosfs_t`.

I checked these with this command: `ls -ldZ` where the `Z` was key.
`l` is enough for me, but some used `getfacls` for a more verbose display.

https://superuser.com/questions/617777/how-do-i-auto-mount-a-usb-drive-that-all-users-can-write-to
I had also thought of the `user` mount option, but it is unnecessary now, at least for solving this problem for me.

2 more SELinux commands may have been helpful, but I could not generate any console or log output with them, with or without the '-d' option, `audit2why` and `audit2allow`.
https://opensource.com/article/18/12/troubleshooting-hardware-problems-linux

The firewall commands allowed other systems to connect.

I was able to test locally using these:

```
> smbclient --user="<user>%<password>" -L '//<machine>/<share>'

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
    ...             Disk      
    smbtest         Disk      testing
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba #.#.#)
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available

> smbclient --user="<user>%<password>" '//<machine>/<share>' --command 'ls'
`NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing \*`
> journalctl -u smb -b
......
chdir_current_service: vfs_ChDir(<path>) failed: Permission denied. Current token: uid=#, gid=#, 1 groups: #
......
...NT_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR...
```

I had already set a custom manual mount line for in `/etc/fstab` through the Disks GUI, and manually as well, having it be mounted under `/mnt/...` instead of only to my user under `/run/...` trying to open the permissions for users and groups more, but other had read permission throughout, so that was misleading.

I may have tried other methods from articles such as these but with messy situations encountered these error messages and thought they were completely ineffective:
[Sharing a mounted drive with samba on CentOS7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391673/sharing-a-mounted-drive-with-samba-on-centos7)

```
mount: <path>: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sd??, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

SELinux: mount invalid.  Same superblock, different security settings for (dev sd??, type exfat)
```

```
> sudo semanage fcontext --add --type "samba_share_t" '/mnt/...'
ValueError: File specification can not include spaces
```

That was incorrect anyway, as I needed the mentioned mask option to mount anyway, so I did not need to work out a correct file context pattern that worked such as suffixes like `(/.*)?` or partial names with wildcards too, where I had the idea when trying this command: `sudo semanage fcontext -l | less`.

That did not work for me earlier as I saw I was not able to change security settings with a remount, thus why it works later now only using the `context` option alone that I thought I had done already.

It's also possible something is still strange between me using the terminal to mount the drive vs. the Disks GUI now that I had the updated file system table file.  I think I have the same options lines and in the correct order, but one method is still giving me a `dosfs_t`..

Other useful commands:
`sudo umount '/mnt/...'`
`lsblk`
`dmesg | less` Since I have little logs in the var folder for any service, possibly using systemd to contain them.
`smbpasswd`
`smbstatus`
`sudo pdbedit -L`
`cat /etc/passwd | grep <user>`